# Нужно вычислить тип совпадения строки В и строки А

Tags: python-3.x

Есть строки A — название стартапа Алисы и строка B — название стартапа Зелибобы. Обе строки имеют одинаковую длину N. Для каждой позиции строки B, нужно вычислить тип совпадения в этой позиции со строкой A.
Если Вi=Аi, то в позиции i тип совпадения должен быть равен Р (от слова plagiarism).
Если Вi != Аi, но существует другая позиция , такая что Вi=Аj, то в позиции i тип совпадения должен быть равен S (от слова suspicious).

Важно:
•   Буквы в рамках одной строки могут повторяться.
•   Каждую букву строки A можно использовать не более чем в одном совпадении типа plagiarism или suspicious.
•   Предпочтение всегда отдается типу plagiarism.
•   В случае совпадения типа suspicious, предпочтение всегда отдается самой левой позиции в строке A.
В остальных позициях тип совпадения должен быть равен I (от слова innocent).

```
TEST 1
Ввод       Вывод
CLOUD      PSIIP
CUPID

TEST 2
Ввод       Вывод
ALICE      SPPII
ELIBO

TEST 3
Ввод         Вывод
ABCBCYA      IPSSPIP
ZBBACAA**
```

Мой код:

```
def main(a, b):
    res = ''
    n = len(b)
    for i in range(n):
        if b[i] == a[i]:
            res += 'P'

        elif b[i] != a[i]:
            if b[i] in a:
                res += 'S'
            else:
                res += 'I'
    return res

print(main('CLOUD', 'CUPID'))
print(main('ALICE', 'ELIBO'))
print(main('ABCBCYA', 'ZBBACAA'))
```

Выводит:
PSIIP, SPPII, IPSSPSP

Comment: А что, ваш код работает неверно? Стоит только оптимизировать, чтоб каждый раз не искать по строке - сделать сет из символов А

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос. Но мне кажется за один цикл решить его нельзя, так как ошибка как раз и происходит из-за невозможности предсказать **P** в конце.

Поэтому мое решение (может не настолько же элегантное) но в первом цикле помимо отметки совпадений сохраняет статистику по буквам чтобы потом их попарно объединять если получиться во втором цикле вызывающем дважды `set_I_or_S` для каждой не выясненной позиции.

Все **пункты условий** соблюдаются, а что касается кода то `set_I_or_S` можно переписать с `return` при желании, ну или вообще код написать иначе используя эту же идею.

```
def main(a, b):
    res = ['?'] * len(b) # массив с нужным размером
    ad = {}  # для подсчета количества букв
    bd = {}  # для подсчета количества букв
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if (b[i] == a[i]):
            res[i] = 'P'
        else: # считаем буквы в обоих словах
            bd[a[i]] = ( bd[a[i]] if a[i] in bd else 0 ) + 1
            ad[b[i]] = ( ad[b[i]] if b[i] in ad else 0 ) + 1

    for i in range(len(b)):
        if (res[i] == '?'):
            set_I_or_S(b[i], bd, i, res)
            set_I_or_S(b[i], ad, i, res)

    return ''.join(res)

def set_I_or_S(letter, dictionary, i, res):
    if (letter in dictionary and dictionary[letter] != 0):
        dictionary[letter] -= 1 # вычитаем букву из словаря
        # S если буква была в предыдущем словаре иначе I
        res[i] =  'I' if res[i] == '?' else 'S'

def test(a, b, c):
    res = main(a, b)
    compare = res == c
    print(res, compare)

test('CLOUD', 'CUPID', 'PSIIP')
test('ALICE', 'ELIBO', 'SPPII')
test('ABCBCYA', 'ZBBACAA', 'IPSSPIP')
```

Выводит: **PSIIP** True, **SPPII** True, **IPSSPIP** True

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такое решение:
В первом цикле проставляем буквы `P`. а во втором бежим по индексам, которые мы еще не проверяли для строки `b`, и для строки `a`.
При этом для строки `b` мы создаем список нужных индексов единожды (исключаем буквы `P`), а для строки `a` - каждую итерацию цикла по строке `b` для обновления списка уже проверенных символов.
Для каждого индекса из строки `a` происходит проверка на совпадение `b[i]==a[j]` и если ни один символ для текущего `i` не совпадает - пишем `I`.

```
def check(a, b):
    res = [' ']*len(a)
    used = set()
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i]==a[i]:
            res[i] = 'P'
            used.add(i)

    for i in sorted(set(range(len(b))) - used):
        for j in sorted(set(range(len(a))) - used):
            if b[i]==a[j]:
                res[i] = 'S'
                used.add(j)
                break
        else:
            res[i] = 'I'

    return ''.join(res)

def test(a, b, c):
    res = check(a, b)
    assert res==c
    print(res)

test('CLOUD', 'CUPID', 'PSIIP')
test('ALICE', 'ELIBO', 'SPPII')
test('ABCBCYA', 'ZBBACAA', 'IPSSPIP')
```